# pytube YouTube Stream video downloading KeyError "bitrate"

Tags: pytube

i am trying to download VATEX dataset videos from youtube utilizing pytube. Some videos are unavailable and some can be downloaded but there is a problem with some videos. Code throws KeyError in some videos one of them is KeyError "Bitrate".

```
# download youtube videos start time to end time from id.
def download_clip(self, video_id, download_folder) -> None:

    '''
        Download youtube videos start time to end time from id.
    '''

    # youtube video url.
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video_id

    yt = YouTube(url)
    try:
        yt = yt.streams.filter(file_extension="mp4", resolution="360p").first().download(output_path=str(download_folder), filename=video_id)
        print("Downloaded: " + video_id)
        return True
    except pytube.exceptions.VideoUnavailable:
        print("Video Unavailable: " + video_id)
        return False
    except KeyError:
        print("Key Error: " + video_id)
        return False
```

Why this happens and if possible how to download the videos i checked youtube and videos throw KeyError exists and available in youtube.

KeyError: "Bitrate"

Example KeyError video id:

```
Key Error: kMKS2QpFTVI
```

The problem arises at ***streams.py line:60***:

```
self.bitrate: Optional[int] = stream["bitrate"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In streams.py change line:60 from:

```
self.bitrate: Optional[int] = stream["bitrate"]
```

to:

```
try:
    self.bitrate: Optional[int] = stream["bitrate"]
except KeyError:
    print("Key Error: bitrate assigned 30")
    self.bitrate = 30
```